# Possibly unhandled rejection: in laravel With Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

How To fix:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8000/api/image","data":{"felhasznalonev":"fdgfgfg"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}
>    Angularjs Controller :

This my AngularJS Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     var BACKEND_URL = "http://localhost:8000";
     $scope.regSubmit = function(){
     $http({
        method: "POST",
        url:BACKEND_URL + '/api/image',
        data: {felhasznalonev: $scope.felhasznalonev},
    }).then(function(data){
        alert(data.msg)
   });
  }
});
```

laravel route :
  This My laravel Route

```
Route::post('api/image' , 'AdmindashController@uploadImage');
```

laravel Controller

```
public function uploadImage(){
    $input = Input::json();
    $input_array = (array)$input;

    $rules = array(
        'felhasznalonev' => 'required'
    );

    $val = Validator::make($input_array, $rules);

    if(! $val->fails() ) {
        $data = array('msg' => 'all good');
    } else {
        $data = array('msg' => $val->errors->all());
    }

    return Response::json($data);
}
```